Rankx function after finding the minimum of each category
Question:
Hello, I'm analyzing data for a video game company using Power BI. In my 'Dim Game' table, I have various details about video games, including turnover, game type, payout, and release date. I've noticed that some game names are repeated in the table.
Now, I want to create a combined DAX measure named 'CombinedDAX' that calculates the rank of the most recent games where the 'MinDateFlag' is 1. However, I'm not sure how to handle the repeated game names and ensure that the 'MinDateFlag' selects the minimum date for each game.
Can you guide me through the steps to create this combined DAX measure?
CombinedDAX:
CombinedDAX = 
VAR MinDateFlag = 
    IF(
        'Dim Game'[Release Date] = CALCULATE(MIN('Dim Game'[Release Date]), ALLEXCEPT('Dim Game', 'Dim Game'[Game Name])),
        1,
        0
    )
VAR RecentGamesRank = 
    IF(
        MinDateFlag = 1,
        RANKX(
            FILTER('Dim Game', MinDateFlag = 1),
            'Dim Game'[Release Date],
            ,
            DESC,
            Dense
        ),
        BLANK()
    )
RETURN
    RecentGamesRank

Let me know if you need further assistance!

Can you share some data please ?

What about creating a calculated column and filter the visual/report based on that using the "EARLIER" function ?
EarliestReleaseDateByGame = 
RANKX(
    FILTER(
        ALL('Dim Game'),
        'Dim Game'[Game Name] = EARLIER('Dim Game'[Game Name])
    ),
    'Dim Game'[Release Date],
    ,
    ASC
)


